# How to get page source of page at another domain (in Javascript!)

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the source page of a webpage on a different domain. I know this is easily done with PHP for example but I would like to do it in Javascript because I am getting results from a page and if I use a server-side language, the original website will block the calls since they come from the same IP. However, if the calls are done on the client side, it is like the user request the results each time (different user, different IP, no original site blocking me). Is there a way to do that (even if not in Javascript but client-side).

To clarify the code I want will be applied to an HTML page so I can get the results, style them, add/delete, etc then display them to the user.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modern browsers support cross-domain AJAX calls but the target site has to allow them by using special headers in the reply. Apart from that, there is no pure Javascript solution AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows you can use [HTA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_Application)

An HTA can access anything crossdomain in an iframe for example

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: It answers it as much as the accepted answer. If the OP wants an example, he can comment on my answer

Comment: Maybe I incorrectly "flagged" it as not an answer but the OP did not say he wanted a Window's only solution. Also I thought this could have been a comment on the question or on the accepted answer(which at least says that there is no way to do it right for every case with Javascript only.)

Comment: No problem. It was not a comment. It was information that could be expanded upon in case the OP was on windows and needed this for himself. I use HTA weekly to grab tables from some of our sites while I wait for an api or crossdomain solution. It simplifies grabbing stuff using dom access on a foreign domain

Answer (score 0):

Could you use an `iframe`?  You wont have direct access to the markup to due to cross-domain restrictions, but you can still *display* the third-party page to the user...

```
window.onload = function() {
  var i = document.createElement("IFRAME");
  i.setAttribute("name", "ID_HERE");
  i.setAttribute("id", "ID_HERE");
  i.setAttribute("src", "URL_HERE");
  i.style.maxHeight = "300px";
  i.style.width = "100%";
  document.body.appendChild(i);
}
```

Comment: Well, not really since I only need part of the page returned not all of it. Is there an easy way to display part of the page only (the length and width might change depending on what's back. Is there a way to decide for example depending on an ID to display that part only?